# Identifying pins on a micro SD card interface on the PCB side

Tags: pcb, identification, sd

I have a Pyle motherboard from an Android-based car audio receiver which has an interface to an SD. I'm trying to identify these pins to make a flat cable to connect a homebrew micro SD card slot.

In the attached picture it has 12 pins of which the two outer ones are GND, but the micro SD card has 9 pins, so I don't know where to connect every pin to this connector.

[image]

The first components inline are marked as T3F and there are 9 of the card pins, but what are the orientations or pins?

Comment: thanks for your corrections, english is not my language but I try to make my best